# How to invoke composer create-project on a private repo?

Tags: php, composer-php

How can I invoke [`composer create-project`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) on a private repository?

When running `composer create-project vendor/package new-project --repository https://github.com/vendor/package.git` composer throws an Exception

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>    The "https://github.com/vendor/package.git/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

When defining the repository in the global `composer.json` and running `composer create-project vendor/package new-project`, composer throws

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>    Could not find package vendor/package with stability stable.

The private repository has a `composer.json` with the used vendor and package name.

---

Update:

The documentation states that `--repository` can accept

> a JSON string which similar to what the [repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories) key accepts

So I tried specifying that the repository is of type vcs.

The following attempts both result in a ParsingException.

```sh
composer create-project vendor/package new-project --repository '{"type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/vendor/package"}'
```

```sh
composer create-project vendor/package new-project --repository '{"repositories": [{"type": "vcs","url": "https://github.com/vendor/package"}]}'
```

```
  [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 1:
  {type: vcs, url: http
  ^
  Expected one of: 'STRING', '}'
```

Comment: You are mixing up the `--repository` argument of the `create-project` command and the `repositories` section in the composer.json schema. These are not the same.

Comment: The documentation says "Can be either an HTTP URL pointing to a composer repository, a path to a local packages.json file, or a JSON string which similar to what the repositories key accepts." The latter suggests just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Parse error it looks like your double quotes are not escaped properly. Try running the command like this.

```
composer create-project vendor/package new-project --repository "{\"type\": \"vcs\", \"url\": \"https://github.com/vendor/package\"}" --stability=dev
```

Comment: Good thought, but resulting in the same ParsingException.

Comment: What OS are you using? The way to escape double qoutes might be different based on OS. This way worked for me on Win 10.

Comment: Ok, this is weird. Also on Win10. If I copy/paste it, it results in said ParsingException. If I put the command in a batch file and execute it, it works (?!). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When providing an URL to `--repository` option, Composer assumes it is a `composer` type of the repository (basically a Packagist or Satis install). That's why it is searching the `packages.json` file.

The second error message points to your repo not having any tags (or rather, stable versions) and by default, `create-project` uses `stable` stability. To install a development version of your repo, try with:

```
composer create-project --stability=dev elstr/core-skeleton
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I updated my question, trying to specify the `--repository` option as type vcs. The suggestion to use `--stability=dev` did not solve the issue either (the package is tagged as 1.0.0, which , from my understanding, should be stable).